# loss parameter explanation for "sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost

I was training Gradient Boosting Models using sklearn's GradientBoostingClassifier [sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier] when I encountered the "loss" parameter.

The official explanation given from sklearn's page is-

> loss : {‘deviance’, ‘exponential’}, optional (default=’deviance’)
>
> loss function to be optimized. ‘deviance’ refers to deviance (=
>   logistic regression) for classification with probabilistic outputs.
>   For loss ‘exponential’ gradient boosting recovers the AdaBoost
>   algorithm.

[sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)

My question is, according to my limited understanding, 'deviance' loss function is used to probabilistic classification (like Naive-Bayes's probabilistic outputs used for classification).

**What happens for 'exponential' loss function?**
OR
**When should 'exponential' loss function be used**

According to sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier page [sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)

For 'algorithm' parameter-

> algorithm : {‘SAMME’, ‘SAMME.R’}, optional (default=’SAMME.R’)
>
> If ‘SAMME.R’ then use the SAMME.R real boosting algorithm.
>   base_estimator must support calculation of class probabilities. If
>   ‘SAMME’ then use the SAMME discrete boosting algorithm. The SAMME.R
>   algorithm typically converges faster than SAMME, achieving a lower
>   test error with fewer boosting iterations.

This means that 'SAMME.R' (of AdaBoost) is similar to 'deviance' of 'loss' parameter of GradientBoostingClassifier?

Is my understanding correct or I am missing something.

Thanks!